# Escaping commas inside double quotes as field separator in awk

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, awk

I need to add two fields to a csv file. The separator of csv fields is the `comma`, and some fields are inside double quotes. The problem is that, inside the double quoted fields, is posible to also find a comma. How to split that with awk?
The fields result from a mongo export. Th position of these fields might change,

Sample input csv,

```
 DateTime,Dealers,Locations,CallEndTime,TotalDuration
"2018-12-27 12:19:14","Dealer1,Dealer2,Dealer3","Gujarat",,67,,
"2018-12-27 12:19:14","Dealer1,Dealer2","Gujarat,Vadodara",,100,
```

Sample output csv,

```
 DateTime,Dealers,Locations,CallEndTime,TotalDuration
"2019-01-07 11:35:42","Dealer1,Dealer2,Dealer3","Gujarat","2019-01-07 11:36:51",69,,
"2018-12-27 12:19:14","Dealer1,Dealer2","Gujarat,Vadodara","2018-12-27 12:19:14,78",
```

Awk code:

```
BEGIN { FSOFS=","}
NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            f[$i] = i
        }
      }
NR>1  {
        begSecs = mktime( gensub( /[":-]/, " ", "g", $(f["DateTime"]) ) )
        endSecs = begSecs + $(f["TotalDuration"])
        $(f["CallEndTime"]) = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", endSecs)
}
{print}
```

I don't want to consider the commas inside the double quotes as FS, I have seen that this can be done using FPAT but I haven't got any clue about how to use that here in case,

```
BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}
NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            f[$i] = i
        }
      }
NR>1  {
        begSecs = mktime( gensub(/[":-]/," ","g",$(f["DateTime"])) )
        endSecs = begSecs + $(f["TotalDuration"])
        $(f["CallEndTime"]) = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", endSecs)
      }
{print}
```

Comment: Have you seen https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Comment: I have seen that, but I want the all the values to be in comma separated only then I could view it in a csv file, I have no idea how to do that

Comment: Could you add the csv output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example almost work. You are just missing a `,` as the output separator (`OFS=","`) and to put double quotes around the new calculated date. This works:

```
BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS=","}
NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            f[$i] = i
        }
      }
NR>1  {
        begSecs = mktime( gensub(/[":-]/," ","g",$(f["DateTime"])) )
        endSecs = begSecs + $(f["TotalDuration"])
        $(f["CallEndTime"]) = "\"" strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", endSecs) "\""
      }
{print}
```

For the examples given.

But there is quite more about csv's than awk could handle. As other answers already have recommended, use a tool that understand the csv format correctly.

Comment: I tried that, But the comas inside double quotes are also getting considered, I have no Idea why, I tested by using OFS="|", the comas inside double quotes are also getting replaced by OFS.

Comment: @mittu What version of awk are you using? If in GNU awk, call `awk --version`. It works for me with version 4.1.4

Comment: @Issac GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)

Comment: Hmmm. it should work. (1) Check that the `"` are actually ASCII 22 inside the source text file. (2) Are you placing the awk code inside a text file that starts with `#!/bin/awk -f`, called `awkfile` and then using the command `awk -f awkfile textfile` ? @mittu

Comment: 2)Yes I am using like that, I  have an t.awk file which I calls from a .sh file, using 
awk -f  t.awk  textfile,   
1) Sorry, I don't know how to check that @Issac

Comment: Try `grep -P '\x22' file`, grep should highlight in red all the '"' . Or try: `cat inf11 | tr -d '\042'` which should remove all the '"' in the file.

Comment: I can't remove the """ because that will make more fields in the csv, There are many comma seperated fields inside """"

Comment: That is a temporal test to "look" at the results in the command line, not to permanently remove anything. Looking at the output of both commands you will be able to find  if the "double quotes" are actually correct. I don't know what other problem is there that prevents you from using the script provided. In any case: good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use `awk` to parse csv files, better to use dedicated tools, e.g. using python csv module:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv, shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from datetime import datetime 
from datetime import timedelta

tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False)

with open('input.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(tempfile, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        row['CallEndTime']=datetime.strptime(row['DateTime'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + timedelta(seconds=int(row['TotalDuration']))
        writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(tempfile.name, 'output.csv')
```

output.csv:

```
DateTime,Dealers,Locations,CallEndTime,TotalDuration
2018-12-27 12:19:14,"Dealer1,Dealer2,Dealer3",Gujarat,2018-12-27 12:20:21,67
2018-12-27 12:19:14,"Dealer1,Dealer2","Gujarat,Vadodara",2018-12-27 12:20:54,100
```

Answer (score 2):

With csvkit >= 1.0.4 (current development version) you can use `csvsql`:

```
csvsql --query '
    update input
    set CallEndTime = datetime(DateTime,"+"||TotalDuration||" seconds");
' input.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN {
    FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*"
}
```

For example, to extract all the values and replace the separator commas to `--`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "--"; FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"|[^,]*"} NR > 1 { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5 }' input.csv
```

Example output:

```
"2018-12-27 12:19:14"--"Dealer1,Dealer2,Dealer3"--"Gujarat"----67
"2018-12-27 12:19:14"--"Dealer1,Dealer2"--"Gujarat,Vadodara"----100
```

`FS` defines the field delimiter, i.e. it defines what a field **is not**.

`FPAT`, on the other hand, defines what a field **is**.

---

<sub>Btw, the first row in your sample input.csv has 6 values, whereas the second row and the header row suggest there should be 5 columns.</sub>